# Выделение последних строк

Tags: php, mysql

Я знаю, чтобы выделить последние строки, нужно отсортировать их в обратном порядке, т.е. `ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 0,15`, но так строки выделяются с конца, т.е. первой идёт самая последняя запись, а мне надо 15 последних записей, но в нормальном порядке. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оставляйте такую сортировку - и лучше скриптом уже выведите в правильном порядке записи.

Например так:

```
$sqlQuery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ....');
$objects = array();
while ($aVar = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)) {
    $objects[] = $aVar;
}
$cnt = count($objects)-1;
for ($i=$cnt; $i>=0; $i--) {
    // отображаем объект
}
```

Comment: Это нагрузочно, думал можно как-то в запросе сделать

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что это нагрузочно? Нагрузочнее, чем не трогать изначальный результат - да; при этом менее нагружено, чем пересортировывать результат в БД.
В большом количестве высоконагруженных проектов узким местом оказывается именно БД.

Comment: Ну ок, только поправь у себя: 
$cnt = count($objects)-1;

Comment: Точно, поправил :)

Answer (score 2):

Твой запрос с `DESC LIMIT 0,15` выбирает именно те строки, которые тебе и нужны. Отображение и обходы результатов - задача скрипта.